# Linux Mint 18 Sarah boots straight into tty1 console and gui will not load

Tags: linux, boot, linux-mint, gui

### Problem

So the **Linux Mint** login screen suddenly became frozen and the box to type the credentials into is missing and just isn't there any longer.

### I tried

- I restarted the computer it then booted straight into the "tty1" console which is basically my computer minus the GUI i have access to all my files and users through this console.
- I looked up some solutions and someone said something about `gdm` but **Linux Mint** uses `mdm` so I tried restarting `mdm` and it told me the service was masked. I then unmasked it and restarted it then tried restarting my computer.
- I tried using the command "startx" but it just brings up a black screen with the mouse. I can move the mouse around and click but it does nothing.

I rely heavily on the **Linux Mint** GUI and I have no idea how to use it that well without the GUI and I have no idea how this even started and my attempts to solve on my own have thus far fallen short.

This is beyond my knowledge of Linux and computers in general so I was curious is someone on **SuperUser** could provide me any help.

Comment: Just in case it helps try to ["add `X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=10` to the .desktop file in `~/.config/autostart/` because I saw that the mint-updater does the same. The autostart is delayed by ten seconds, less would probably be sufficient but I haven't tested it."](https://github.com/owncloud/client/issues/1739)